# ActionScript Basic Question

Tags: actionscript-3

i've only ever created external .as files that extended a class such as sprite.  now i just want to create one that doesn't extend anything and call it from a frame script.

```
package
{
public class Test
    {
    public function Test(val:Number, max:Number)
        {
        trace(val, max);
        }
    }
}
```

from my frame script of an .fla that is in the same folder as Test.as, i'll write this:

```
Test(50, 100);
```

this produces the following error:

```
1137: Incorrect number of arguments.  Expected no more than 1.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code will be interpreted as cast to Test. It makes no sense to cast 2 numbers as a Test object.

What you want is an instance (an object) of the class Test.

For this, you need the `new` operator.

```
var testInstance:Test = new Test(50,100);
```

Then, you can use your object as needed, for example, calling methods, setting or getting values, etc.

```
testInstance.someMethod("hello");
testInstance.someNumber = 10;
var n:Number = testInstance.someNumber;
//  etc...
```

Comment: clearly my coffee hasn't kicked in yet.  wow.  i'm confident this tops my all time most stupid questions.  once again, thanks.

Comment: Haha, no worries! Give Java a little time to sink in.